# How to Partially Construct DAGs Using Workspace Entities for a Single Deployment During Refactoring in Dataform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker, dataform

If you've worked on Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAGs) in Dataform, you may have wondered: how can you ensure that the ref function (which resolves table dependencies) targets entities in your workspace, particularly during refactoring? This becomes especially relevant if you aim to capture all cascading changes in a single deployment. Consider a simple scenario where table B references table A.

Before Changes
A.sql

```sql
select val1 as foo from source
```

B.sql

```sql
select foo, count(*) n from ${ref("schema.A")}
```

After Changes
A.sql

```sql
select val1 as boo from source
```

B.sql

```sql
select boo, count(*) n from ${ref("schema.A")}
```

Usually, the workflow involves making changes in your workspace, previewing the changes, and then moving on to code reviews and deployment. However, the catch is that using ref("schema.A") in Dataform often targets the production table A instead of the one in your workspace.

The main question then is: Is there a way to make sure that ref() targets entities in your workspace, allowing you to capture all the changes—including their ripple effects—in a single deployment?

Other tools like Looker offer a DEV mode, where you can work with workspace entities without affecting production tables. How can you replicate a similar approach in Dataform?